# Chromium Kiosk - Navigation Menu

Tags: chromium, kiosk

I am very new to Raspberry

I am trying to add the below HTML page in Chromium Kiosk - which is not supporting - is their anyway i can achieve the below ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <frameset Rows="10%,*">
        <frame src="frame_a.htm">
        <frame src="frame_b.htm">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

All I need is to display a navigation bar to refresh the home page - I am trying to create a image gallery.

Please let me know is their any way I can achieve the same

If No - Please let me know what is the work around for the same

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not supporting"? Could you describe exactly what happens? Additionally, is `<framesrc="frame_b.htm">` a typo - you probably meant `<frame src="frame_b.htm">`?

Comment: @Aurora0001 - Sorry framesrc is a typo pls ignore it - I am trying the above code as a basic HTML page - when try to open in chromium browser lunix - I am not getting two frames - Where as when i  try the same in windows OS browser it works as excepted - I guess this helps !!!

Comment: @Ramesh which version of Windows/Browser do you use?

Comment: Windows 10 OS (Google Chrome is up to date Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)) - works fine but not on Raspberry OS chromium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for the question - I didn't release Chromium supports HTML5 where `<frameset>` has been removed from HTML5

So, I found an alternative solution for the same as below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<frameset framespacing="0" rows="150,*" frameborder="0" noresize>
    <frame name="top" src="http://www.npscripts.com/framer/demo-top.html" target="top">
    <frame name="main" src="video.html" target="main">
</frameset>
</html>
```

The above code works perfectly and helped me in creating a navigation bar in Kiosk chromium browser

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: frameset and frames are so old that frankly I thought this question was an old question from 10- years ago. Please do not use frames.. its very old and all broswers are tying to kill it. You should only use frames for very special cases. And this is not it. You should go through some HTML5 tutorials, maybe bootstrap too and a bit of jQuery. Or just jump into Angular if you are brave.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.